# Powershell - Merging Results in one table

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am new to powershell.

I am trying to create a report that shows AD accounts that expire soon.

The report should include the User Name, AccountExpirationDate and the Manager.

I have the following so far:

```
$users = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "7" | Select-Object Name,AccountExpirationDate | Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate

$manager = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "7" | Get-aduser    -Properties Manager | Select-Object @{n="ManagerName";e={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties displayName).DisplayName}}
```

Is there anyway I can merge the results in one table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be lazy, just get the `Manager` attribute on your first pass and juggle it through the pipeline to your calculated property.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan "7" |
  Get-ADUser -Properties Name, AccountExpirationDate, Manager |
    Select-Object Name, AccountExpirationDate, @{ name = 'Manager'; expression = { (Get-ADuser $_.Manager -Properties displayName).displayName } } |
      Sort-Object AccountExpirationDate
```